# Simple Implementation of QZ-Algorithm fails in MatLab

Tags: numerical-methods

i am still very new to numerics, but i have a question concerning a very simple Implementation of the QZ-Algorithm in Matlab.

My Code Looks like:

```
% QZ-Algorithm-Implementation
% 1. Step: A and B reduced to generalized upper Hessenberg Form: 
% 1. A = U*H*V^H and B = U*R*V^H
% (H upper Hessenberg; R upper triagonal; U, V orthogonal)
%
% 2. Step: H and R reduced to generalized schur Form:
% 2. H = Q*S*Z^H and R = Q*T*Z^H
% (Q, Z optionally computable)
%
% 3. Step: Eigenvalues Lambda_i = alpha_i / beta_i

function [lambda, errors, iterations] = QZAlgo(A, B, precision, angle)
    AB = A;
    iterations = 0;
    errors = zeros(1, length(A));


    % Check plausibility with Matlab
    [AA, BB, Q, Z, V, W] = qz(A, B);
    lambdaMatlab = diag(AA) ./ diag(BB);


    % 1. Step: Create Hessenberg-Form
    H = hess(A);
    R = hess(B);
    %H = A;
    %R = B;

    % 2. Step: Create Schur-Form
    S = schur(H);
    T = schur(R);

    % 3. Step: Compute Eigenvalues
    lambda = diag(S) ./ diag(T);

    if (abs(lambda(1) - lambdaMatlab(1)) < abs(lambda(2) - lambdaMatlab(1)))
        errors(1) = abs(lambda(1) - lambdaMatlab(1));
        errors(2) = abs(lambda(2) - lambdaMatlab(2));
        %disp(sprintf('%f -- %f / %f -- %f', lambda(1), lambdaMatlab(1), lambda(2), lambdaMatlab(2)));
    else
        errors(1) = abs(lambda(1) - lambdaMatlab(2));
        errors(2) = abs(lambda(2) - lambdaMatlab(1));
        %disp(sprintf('%f -- %f / %f -- %f', lambda(1), lambdaMatlab(2), lambda(2), lambdaMatlab(1)));
    end

    disp(sprintf('%d°: 1. Error: %f; 2. Error: %f; Iterations: %i; Precision: %f', angle, errors(1), errors(2), iterations, precision));

end
```

I'm Aware that all the really complicated stuff is hidden in the hess- and schur-functions of matlab, but still i do not achieve reasonable results.

Take matrices A and B as Example:

```
A =

   0.0045 - 0.0458i   1.9946 + 0.0956i
   1.9946 + 0.0956i   0.0103 - 0.1429i

B =

   2.0020 + 0.0006i   0.0045 - 0.0458i
   0.0045 - 0.0458i   1.9946 + 0.0956i
```

My implementation gives me this solution

```
lambda =

  -0.9904 - 0.1036i
   1.0012 - 0.0567i
```

but the solution of matlab is much more better:

```
lambdaMatlab =

   0.9985 - 0.0006i
  -0.9990 - 0.0482i
```

Which step in my code is responsible for the differences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not doing steps simultaneously for both matrices.

```
H = hess(A);
R = hess(B);
```

produces decomposition
$$
A = U H U^\mathsf{H}\\
B = V R V^\mathsf{H}
$$
which is not what you need
$$
A = U H V^\mathsf{H}\\
B = U R V^\mathsf{H}.
$$
To do the latter use `hess(A, B)`. The same applies to Schur form, but no implementation is provided for that in Matlab.

Comment: Thank you, i can see the problem now. Is it possible to provide some pseudo-code or further literatur on how to create the schur form simultaneously for both matrices?

Comment: LAPACK implementation of SHGEQZ references C.B. Moler & G.W. Stewart, "An Algorithm for Generalized Matrix Eigenvalue Problems", SIAM J. Numer. Anal., 10(1973), pp. 241--256. http://lib.gen.in/next/MTAuMjMwNy8yMTU2MzUz/10.2307@2156353.pdf